# How to implement annoucement system Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am currently developping a wbsite and I may need to put sometime a banner at the top of the website displaying some annoucement like `Due to maintenance, the website won't be available from 1am to 5am` etc... I'll have a table with annoucement like below

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------+
| id | start_date          | end_date            | text                   |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------+
| 1  | 2017-08-12 12:30:00 | 2017-08-12 13:00:00 | This is an annoucement |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------+
```

So I would have to check if an annoucement is currently running. I wonder what is the best way / more professionnal to implement this. I just need to display it on the home page. I could make a php query into the blade.php but I don't think it's the best way.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try with whereBetween to check the time and display what ever message you want.

Comment: Go to the controller that serves the homepage and do a query like @yoeunes says. Then inject it to the blade view and print the text

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
$active_annoucements = \DB::table('annoucements')
            ->where('start_date', '<', \Carbon\Carbon::now())
            ->where('end_date', '>', \Carbon\Carbon::now())
            ->get();
```